# Why am I getting "Runtime Error: AddressSanitizer: DEADLY SIGNAL"?

Tags: c++, c++11, debugging, runtime-error

While trying to solve [this leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-pattern/), I was getting a **Runtime Error: AddressSanitizer: DEADLY SIGNAL**.

The complete Error message is

```
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==30==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address (pc 0x0000002b0452 bp 0x7ffd8e6682e0 sp 0x7ffd8e667a78 T0)
==30==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==30==Hint: this fault was caused by a dereference of a high value address (see register values below).  Dissassemble the provided pc to learn which register was used.
    #3 0x7f73671f7d6b  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6+0x144d6b)
    #10 0x7f7366d6b0b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
==30==ABORTING
```

Problem Description:

> Given a "pattern" and a string "s", find if "s" follows the same "pattern".
>
> Here follow means a full match, such that there is a bijection between a letter in pattern and a non-empty word in s.

```
Example 1:

Input: pattern = "abba", s = "dog cat cat dog"
Output: true
Example 2:

Input: pattern = "abba", s = "dog cat cat fish"
Output: false
```

Here is my solution:

```
class Solution {
    public:
    bool wordPattern(string pattern, string s) {
        vector<string>vec;
        string tmp = "";
        for(int i=0 ; i<s.size() ; i++){
            if(s[i] == ' '){
                vec.push_back(tmp);
                tmp.clear();
                continue;
            }
            tmp += s[i];
        }
        map<char , set<string> > mp;
        for(int i=0 ; i<pattern.size() ; i++){
            mp[pattern[i]].insert(vec[i]);
        }
        bool flag = 0;
        for(int i=0 ; i<pattern.size() ; i++){
            char x = pattern[i];
            if(mp[x].size() != 1)
                flag = 1;
        }
        return !flag;
    }
};
```

Comment: `for(int i=0 ; i<pattern.size() ; i++){ mp[pattern[i]].insert(vec[i]); }` This loop assumes that the number of elements in `vec` is the same or greater than the number of characters in `pattern`. Is this the case? If that doesn't hold, then the program exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an index out of bounds. And there are reasons to believe that this doesn't hold; for example, if `s` doesn't contain any spaces at all, then `vec` would be empty.

Comment: Usually `Runtime Error: AddressSanitizer` indicates you are trying to access some invalid memory space. The issue @IgorTandetnik mentioned here is the reason, getting this error. The problem did not guarantee that `pattern.length() == words(s)`.